# Problems installing and booting 16.04 on new laptop

Tags: thinkpad

I have a brand new, out of the box Lenovo Thinkpad 11e. I've installed 16.04 LTS using a USB, though I had to do this via the desktop of the 'try Ubuntu without installing' option as the screen would freeze on the regular install option. Now it's installed though, I'm having similar problems when trying to boot or shut down/restart (the screen will freeze, though it will boot eventually). I've ran all the updates, but that's not helped either. I've tried reinstalling, but the screen also freezes when trying both install options on the USB.

I've installed Ubuntu on multiple systems in the past and have never had a problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Lee, I feel your pain. I wanted to upgrade too 16.04LTS, but have since resigned myself to just upgrading the kernel too 4.4.x, which with the 14.04LTS already installed worked excellently. One thing you will need is synaptic (I would recommend synaptic to every install) to easily get and install the newer kernel. I am sure there are many other ways but I personally love EASY  ;?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've had even less success with 14.04 LTS; I was able to install it, but it won't book at all. Exactly the same with Linux Mint. This is exasperating! Plus, there's practically nothing out from people running Ubuntu on the 11e (except from an apparent thumbs up on the Lenovo forum). Am I just banging my head against a brick wall?!